# Controlling relay through an optocoupler

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, esp8266

I'm trying to control a relay through a TCMT4100 optocoupler but I can't get it to work. I tried to check the TCMT4100's datasheet, but I don't quite understand which forward current should I look for, so I'm not sure if the 470 Ω resistor is the right value for the optocoupler's LED. I used it because I saw it in another project being used with this optocoupler.

I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

I [image]

Comment: this makes no sense! You have an optocoupler, but seemingly still have shared ground between the rest of the circuit and your relay.

Comment: Moreover, the relay itself will provide isolation. The relay will also need more coil current than the optocoupler can deliver. Try to replace the optocoupler all together with a bog-standard N-FET and freewheeling diode across the relay coil.

Comment: wow, [that relay type your schematic uses](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Power-Relays_Ningbo-Songle-Relay-SRD-12VDC-SL-C_C30431.html) has a strange pinout! The switched output crosses the coil contacts and ends up on the "low voltage" side of the relay. Make **very** sure you're not getting too close to 230 V with your low-voltage electronics! This relay pinout is *not* your friend in terms of safety!

Comment: @MarcusMüller The "optocoupler plague" we see all the time here is likely explained by some Arduino board having fool proof design where they used optocouplers just in case someone decides to lick on the powered relay contacts while showing the Arduino up their nose at the same time, something like that. I believe the weird relay comes from the same design, this sort of junk: https://www.circuits-diy.com/4-channel-relay-module-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: Yes I know. I'm not planning on using it, I just had them at home so I'm testing with them but without load.

Comment: @k0cka Usually you draw the schematics first and then build the circuit. Now you made schematics afterwards with errors so it does not match what you built. It is hard to know what else is different between schematics and what you built.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84181/tcmt4100.pdf) is quite clear: in the table "Electrical Characterisitics" under "INPUT" are the specifications for the input. It's a forward voltage of typically 1.35 V at 50 mA.

So, your series resistor should be (3.3 V - 1.35 V) / (50 mA) = 39 Ω.

Note that your optocoupler has a peak permissible current of 100 mA; your relay will quite possibly draw a lot more, even during continuous operation. So, wrong choice completely.

You're missing the freewheeling diode across the coil; the reverse voltage spike your relay's coil will produce on being turned off rapidly would very likely fry the output transistors of your optocoupler.

Not to mention that your relay already is for isolaton, and that you're connecting the grounds on both sides of your optocoupler, anyways.

*You don't need an optocoupler*, you need a logic-level N-channel MOSFET from the looks of it. Don't forget to include a freewheeling diode across the relay's windings!

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I though so, but the guy in the other project used a 470ohm resistor and it was working for him, so I was confused. So if I'm sharing the same ground for the 3.3V and also the 12V section, there is no point in using an optocoupler?

Comment: "you need a logic-level N-channel MOSFET from the looks of it" Yep, or for hobbyist purposes just some ULN Darlington with freewheel diodes built-in. They aren't industrial quality parts, but easy to build with for hobbyists.

Comment: @k0cka nope, no point. isolation makes sense when you need to either a) spearate potentials, which you're not doing when you're sharing ground or especially b) when you need to make really sure that malfunctions / EMI don't lead to conducted high-voltage pulses, and such a fault really doesn't care about whether it gets conducted through the power supply or through ground. Good rule of thumb for "it worked for the other guy" is "ignore, unless you understand *why*".

Answer (score 0):

The relay coil current is less than 40 mA.  If there is only one relay to be controlled, this can be done with just about any small signal BJT transistor or MOSFET.

2N4401, 2N3904, 2N2222m 2N7000/7002

A bipolar transistor will require a base current limiting resistor.  With the FET there is no need for a gate resistor.  Both transistor types will require a diode across the relay coil.  1N914, 1N4148, etc.

Comment: There's also BJTs with built-in resistors, [example](https://www.nexperia.com/products/bipolar-transistors/resistor-equipped-transistors-rets/PUMH11.html).

Comment: True, but those are relatively rare compared to the slew of jellybean transistors plus a 1-cent resistor.

Answer (score 0):

For 12V relays, a [ULN2003A](https://www.ti.com/product/ULN2003A) is about the best solution if you don't need isolation. It includes flyback diodes (tie COM to +12) and there are 7 drivers in one inexpensive package. It does not provide isolation but neither does your present circuit. Calculate the maximum total current carefully for good reliability.

Relays do **not** provide perfect isolation, particularly noticeable when they are switching inductive loads and it's well worth considering (real, not placebo, with a separate isolated power supply for the relay coils) optoisolation and evaluating the paths capacitively coupled currents will take and what mischief that can result in.

On a 4-layer or more board with ground planes and modern processors it's less of a problem than it used to be, but poor design can still lead to enormous headaches with random resets and lock-ups of processors. Not to mention noise showing up in millivolt sensor readings in analog circuits.

Comment: @Justme That will solve the noise issue then.

Comment: I'm a newbie in this so I actually don't know if I need isolation because I don't know the disadvantages. Currently I have a 12V power supply which is powering the relays and a K7803-500R3 converter for 3.3V section. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The two supplies share a common ground so they are similar to just having one. Isolation won't help much here, good layout will.

Comment: I was looking at the ULN2003A and if I understand it right, it needs high input signal right? But I have read in another topic, that "PCF8575 output pins can only be pulled high weakly, so cannot source enough current to light a led. But they can be pulled low strongly, sinking up to 20mA...". So I'm not sure if I can control this transistor with the PCF8575.

Comment: I added 74HC14 logic inverter with the ULN2003A, this is my schematic now - https://drive.google.com/file/d/125OOY26mZ6QvcNYxgmb3jMTDMMcN70Ki/view?usp=drive_link. Would you mind reviewing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your IO expander does not work because it is missing a power supply due to an error in the schematics.

Also put a diode over relay coil so that the optoisolator does not damage when you power off the coil after the first time you have turnef coil power on.

Comment: Oh yeah I see, I just drew the schematic in a hurry and I didn't noticed that I routed it wrong. But in reality I just have it directly connected to 3.3V

Comment: @k0cka Oh well, if the actual hardware does not match the schematics, we cannot know why your hardware does not work.

Comment: I know sorry, that was the only missmatch in the schematics.

Comment: @k0cka obviously, fix the schematic, then!